Laravel [NGINX] 404 NOT FOUND on sub-directory or images even though they exist
NOTE: This project works well on my localhost.
I installed this Laravel project on my server with Nginx as the webserver. It installed fine since I followed the instructions but when I upload an image to replace a current one like: avatar, logos, favicons; they're uploaded but do not show up. The image field shows broken images.
Browser console says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and when I try previewing the image following the link provided, it says "404 | NOT FOUND" even though it exists and that is the correct URL.
I have done all what I know to do like clearing Laravel's routes, config and cache. I have tried setting the folder's permission to 777 just to be sure. I've set all the necessary permissions the way they should be set but not working still. I even had to install Apache webserver because I thought Nginx had the problem only to get the same error. I had to revert back to Nginx.
I can't visit a sub-directory I created myself like "/main/" or view an uploaded image using the correct URL.

I turned off NGINX: systemctl stop nginx
I installed Apache and started the service; moved the project to a new directory, updated the Virtual hosts record (of cos I used "public"). The same issue
I've set file and directory permissions for all files and directories in the project directory: 644 and 755; still the same error.
I made sure the main project directory is owned by www-data; did all that with chgrp, chown. The same issue

PROJECT: solut.website.com
user@localhost:/var/www$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 16 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  8 15:26 solut.website.com

PROJECT ROOT DIR & FILES
user@localhost:/var/www$ ls -la solut.website.com/
total 83748
drwxr-xr-x 16 www-data www-data     4096 Apr  8 15:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root         4096 Apr  8 09:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data www-data     4096 Dec 23  2022 app
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     1686 Dec 23  2022 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data     4096 Dec 23  2022 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     2727 Apr 20  2023 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   411030 Apr 20  2023 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 Apr  3  2023 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data     4096 Dec 23  2022 database
-rw-r--r--  1 ample    www-data      258 Dec 23  2022 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 ample    www-data      589 Mar 28 09:09 .env
-rw-r--r--  1 ample    www-data      590 Mar 28 08:15 .env_backup
-rw-r--r--  1 ample    www-data      912 Dec 23  2022 .env.example
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 May 28  2023 erpgo
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 84783392 May 28  2023 erpgo.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 ample    www-data      152 Dec 23  2022 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--  1 ample    www-data       16 Feb 23  2023 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 ample    www-data      931 Dec 23  2022 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x  3 ample    www-data     4096 Apr 28  2023 .idea
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data      563 Mar  9  2023 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data     4096 Dec 23  2022 lang
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 May 28  2023 main
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data      682 Apr 26  2023 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   406860 Apr 26  2023 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data      717 May 27  2023 phptest.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     1175 Dec 23  2022 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data     4096 Jun  5  2023 public
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     3958 Dec 23  2022 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data     4096 Feb 17  2023 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 Mar 28 17:12 routes
drwxrwxrwx 19 www-data www-data     4096 May 28  2023 storage
-rw-r--r--  1 ample    www-data      162 Dec 23  2022 .styleci.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data      487 Dec 23  2022 tailwind.config.js
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data     4096 Dec 23  2022 tests
drwxr-xr-x 69 www-data www-data     4096 Apr 20  2023 vendor
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     5046 Apr 28  2023 verification.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data      596 Dec 23  2022 webpack.mix.js

PROJECT .htaccess file
user@localhost:/var/www$ cat solut.website.com/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|.ttf|\.svg)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>

## NGINX Virtual Host
user@localhost:/var/www$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/solut.website.com.conf
server {
        # Server
        server_name             solut.website.com; # managed by Certbot

        # Root directory
        root                    /var/www/solut.website.com/public;

        # Laravel Deployment: laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#nginx
        # LD 1
        add_header              X-Frame-Options         "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header              X-Content-Type-Options  "nosniff";

        # Index page
        index                   index.php index.html index.htm; #was previously DISABLED

        # LD 2
        charset                 utf-8;

        location / {
                try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; #because of LARAVEL
        }

        # LD 3
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        # LD 4
        error_page              404                     /index.php;

        # Setup PHP
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        # LD 6
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }

        # Disable .htaccess from being served
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        # Serving static files
        location ~* \.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)$ {
                expires         max;
                log_not_found   off;
                access_log      off;
        }

        # Serving public directory
        location ~* ^/public/(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js)/(.*)$ {
                rewrite         ^/public/(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js)/(.*)$        /public/$1/$2   break;
        }

        #location ~ /* {
                #rewrite                ^/(.*)$         /index.php?_url=/$1;
        #}


        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/solut.website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/solut.website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
        if ($host = solut.website.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        listen                  80                      ;
        listen                  [::]:80                 ;
        server_name             solut.website.com;
        return                  404; # managed by Certbot
}

Nothing in the Logs have been helpful either other than "404"

Show your code where you are trying to display images or external files in the output, i.e. in the blade file.

It's not webserver related issue. Your problem is with defining image paths in blade files or link to storage directory.

@EHFShahab what about the directory I can't access? Don't forget, the same project works well on my localhost without having to modify anything else asides setting up the right permissions. Why then is the localhost working well (but online isn't) if it's a problem with defining image paths?

@AntonyMN one thing to note is that it all works fine in my localhost..so, does this really have to do with a blade file?

If it works well on your localhost, I'd say this should be your preferred host to run the application as it has been made for it specifically. This is also visible in the file listing in your question, it contains many files that do not belong onto a remote server. Stay local, it not only works, but it also prevents you from information disclosure. Discuss this with your supervisor, they should be able to give you more clear instructions and all the support you need.


it says "404 | NOT FOUND"

Note the vertical bar, it identifies "it" as Laravel.
Only you use Nginx to run Laravel, this is a route handled by Laravel now, not of the webserver.

even though it exists and that is the correct URL.

Note that here, "it" it is a file and that "is the correct URL" is irrelevant as for your Laravel you want to know if a route exists (not a file) and that the correct route is in use (and not a correct URL only).
TLDR: Sounds like a configuration issue. Destroy the server and provision it a new, then deploy the application.
It normally then works and even if not, you have limited the configuration error to the deployment routine and the server provisioning. Continue there then with your trouble-shooting as you have now managed to make the problem reproducible.

Thanks for this. It is the same issue with any server. Without changing configurations except for the .env file, this same project works so well on my localhost; the images are well-displayed but it just doesn't work on the live server.

Yes, very good when you can reprodiuce it! How do you build the deployable? And IIRC the .env file does not belong into it. And if you can also reproduce the good case, compare what you do different local compared to remote. And check if you get a sysadmin at hand if they can spare a bit of time. They also often have good ideas how to improve a setup.

Try php artisan storage:link and ensure that the folder public/storage exitsts. Also make sure that all images are placed in the folder public, and that you are using asset() to access them in your templates.
Also, in the .env make sure that you have the APP_URL defined properly. If you are using php artisan serve on port 8000, you will need to set APP_URL=http://localhost:8000.

Thanks for your reply. The public/storage folder does exists but the images not been displyaed are usually uploaded to this folder: storage/uploads/; that is storage/uploads/logo/, storage/uploads/avatar/, etc. In this case, the URL for an image not found even though it exists is APP_URL/storage/uploads/logo/fav-image.png. How then can I set this up?

Delete the public/storage, and recreate it with php artisan storage:link. Let's start there

Yeah..done that

What is the APP_URL and domain for the application? Are they set the same? What exactly are you entering inside the asset() call? When you visit storage/uploads and public/storage/uploads do you see the same files?

Ensure you have created a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public by running php artisan storage:link as this enables your uploaded files to be web-accessible.
You can also customize the directory as you see fit from the filesystems.php config file. see an example below.
'links' => [
    public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'), // you can customize this as needed
]

You can then access the files via laravel asset helper. e.g. asset('images/007.png');
Tip: If the symlink already exists and is not working for some reason. You can try to unlink the existing symlink by running php artisan storage:unlink followed by running php artisan storage:link
Source

Thank you. Can you please give me more examples? It doesn't seem to work on the online server yet; Localhost has always been working. Say the images not been displayed are located in APP_URL/storage/uploads/, how do I set this up in the filesystems.php file?

Let's see the content of your filesystems.php, only the links array should be sufficient.
